# Dynamic load plugin when using Neovim?

Tags: neovim, plugin

I want to dynamically load the local plugins when using Neovim.

For example, there are some directories `~/plugin1` and `~/plugin2` (they're colorscheme plugins).

When using Neovim, I try to add `~/plugin1` and `~/plugin1/colors` to runtimepath, but it's not working:

```lua
vim.opt.runtimepath:append('~/plugin1')
vim.opt.runtimepath:append('~/plugin1/colors')
```

The error message says `color xxx` is not found.

Then I check `vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_lists()`, and it shows the plugin1 folder is not one of the runtimepath returned.

How could I dynamically add a folder to runtimepath???

Comment: I can't say for Lua, but typically `set runtimepath^=` or `set runtimepath+=` is sufficient. The error message: does it come from the `colorscheme` command? You might want to check whether or not you need to expand `~` when using `vim.opt.runtimepath:append` in Lua.

Comment: The error is `colorscheme xxx` not found, but thanks for your suggest that expand `~`, I will check it.